# Could You Use A Dutch Oven as A Casserole

Tags: meat, cookware

Is there some scientific reason as to why a recipe would suggest using a casserole dish instead of using dutch oven. I understand (that usually) one is ceramics and one is cast iron, but does that mean they are not interchangeable? I am specifically concerned when it comes to cooking meat in the oven

Comment: Not all Dutch ovens are cast iron nor are all casserole dishes ceramic.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a matter of the difference in depth between the two items?

There's a Hungarian layered dish I make with chicken, potatoes, peppers and fresh tomatoes with sauce poured over before baking. If I were to make that in a more shallow casserole dish, I wouldn't even be able to do one layer. A Dutch oven is a necessity. But a lasagne made in a deep Dutch oven would end up swimming in liquid. I know 'cause I tried it once!

Other than examples like that, I'd think many foods could be cooked in either.